# How do I print an entire page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing, screen-capture, cups

For my personal records (e.g. receipts), I like to print a web page in Firefox using CUPS print-to-pdf. This works great when the page layout is narrow. However, if the page is too wide, the output is cut-off on the right. I have tried all the possible options for `shrink to fit`, `scale: 100%`, and `page size/orientation`, but depending on the page's HTML/CSS, the right is still cut-off.

Ideally, I would like to use a tool which can capture the entire page as-is (at the window's width; not formatted for paper), and output it in *.pdf format. Does something like this exist?

Preferred OS: Linux, but I can also use Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried add-ons such as iWeb2x or Print edit?

Comment: I just tried iWeb2X and PrintEdit, as you suggested. iWeb2X seems to have issues with CSS and displays certain elements incorrectly. PrintEdit is a great tool. It looks like it will save me some time, as I sometimes manually delete elements using FireBug.

There are a lot of great tools out there for printing to PDF, but none with an option to output the page as-is, without paper dimensions/margins.

Comment: You may try to use the following extensions: Firebug on Aardvark to play with HTML/CSS before printing; Screengrab to print as PNG image. Aardvark works fine with FF7 if you set option to ignore compatibility check; Screengrab is End-Of-Life, don't know if works with new FF, works fine with FF3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Abduction!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/abduction) seems to work well,

if you dont mind `.png`.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution right now to capture the whole window accurately. It's too bad that no tools exist to output *.pdf in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

Try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It's packaged at least in Debian/Ubuntu.

> **Guide**
>
> To use this software download the latest static release unpack it and run it like
>
> ```
> wkhtmltopdf www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.pdf
> ```
>
> for a list of available options see
>
> ```
> wkhtmltopdf --help
> ```
>
> **Features**
>
> - Convert web pages into PDF documents using webkit
> - Adding headers and footers (static version only)
> - TOC generation (static version only)
> - Batch mode conversions
> - (Linux) No longer requires an XServer to be running (however the X11 client libs must be installed)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try the Chrome browser with “Print to PDF”.

See [Using print preview](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1379552).

Answer (score 0):

[Save as PDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-as-pdf/) might work. That's a firefox addon that can save any page to a PDF file.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what "This" is, because just posting a link isn't very helpful.

Comment: This does not save the current iteration of the page. It appears to send the URL to `pdfcrowd.com` where it is then processed using their servers. It also watermarks the output. Not really what I was looking for.